# My android studio shows graphic on opening activity_main.xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My android studio shows graphically editing instead of the written xml codes. The online curse that i am studying requires me to write the xml codes so please tell me how can i switch to text editing of the visual of my app.

Comment: at the bottom of your graphic preview there are two tabs. "Text" and "Design". Just click on text and switch to that tab

Answer (score 0):

On the bottom of that xml there are 2 tabs. 1st is Design and 2nd is Text. Select text and you should be able to see the xml file of layout.

Answer (score 0):

After open the xml file you can view two button one is TEXT other is DESIGN on the bottom of xml file . using TEXT button u can wright xml file .

Answer (score 0):

Save your XML file to **layouts** folder, then opening the xml file you can view two tabs at bottom. One is TEXT and other is DESIGN. Switch to TEXT button to edit xml file. Check below image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient rep to comment.

In 2022 the buttons have moved and changed names:

At the TOP (right) of the XML visual editor you will see THREE buttons labelled
Code, Split, Design
You want the 'Code' button.